# At what velocity and pressure will water enter a Vacuum chamber?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, vacuum

Assuming we have a chamber with a near-perfect vacuum, and we are at sea level. If the chamber is 4 feet long and 2 feet wide, we forced it underwater and opened a valve that was 1 inch in diameter to let the water flow in. What would be the velocity of the water entering the chamber? If someone knows an equation for this that would be very helpful.

Comment: There is... but it's  not a simple one:    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation

Comment: Holy shit the equation has its own wiki page :-: